# Pytest not finding tests on GitHub actions

Tags: github, pytest, code-coverage, github-actions, pytest-cov

I'm trying to generate code coverage for a python package I work on and created a GitHub action to do this, which uses the [codecov-action](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-action). The workflow looks like this:

```
name: Code Coverage
on: [push]

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@master
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        pip install pytest-cov
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Generate coverage report
      run: |
        pytest --cov=./epispot --cov-report=xml
    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
      with:
        verbose: true
        fail_ci_if_error: true
```

When it's run, it outputs an error, which you can view [here](https://github.com/epispot/epispot/runs/1906681404?check_suite_focus=true). Pytest outputs error code 5 - meaning that no tests were found - but when I run it on my computer, it works properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: your files must be named `*_test.py` or `test_*.py` by default -- I see `*-test.py` -- why it's working locally is beyond me, perhaps you have a local configuration file that's not part of your repository? - a pytest core dev

Comment: @AnthonySottile the test files are all named `test_*.py` under the `tests/CI` folder, I believe.

Comment: `tests/CI` has file names in a correct format, but there're no tests inside the files. Have you read test discovery page https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be not the case with you but I had this issue when I was adding a Python test in a branch but added a Github action with `pytest` to master branch. So, pytest was not finding any tests because there were in fact none.

After I merged master branch with the workflow into that branch with a test, Python build with pytest passed.